# Redirect non-existing subdomain to site

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect mail.my-site.ru to Yandex mail for domain and gmail.my-site.ru to Google mail. I write

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mail\.my-site\.ru$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*) http://mail.yandex.ru/for/my-site.ru$1 [L,R]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gmail\.my-site\.ru$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*) http://google.com/a/my-other-site.ru$1 [L,R]
```

However, mail.my-site.ru redirects well, but gmail.my-site.ru leads to "cannot find gmail.my-site.ru". Both subdomains don't exist. What's wrong?

Comment: Is gmail.my-site.ru directed to your server? (e.g. ping it, does it resolve to the ip of your server?) If not, then it is a problem with the dns records.

Comment: Sorry, seems that mail subdomen exists, it pings. Cannot I redirect non-existing subdomains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sorry, seems that mail subdomen exists, it pings. Cannot I redirect non-existing subdomains?

No. You need to setup a DNS entry for `gmail.my-site.ru` and point it to the same IP address that `mail.my-site.ru` points to. You can use a [CNAME record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) to do this as well.

You'll need to go to the registrar for your domain (my-site.ru) and set that up. Otherwise, your rules look fine. Are you sure you want `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`?

Comment: Thanks! I just created subdomain.